# Css Aligned Top with other element

Tags: html, css

I want to show panel1(div) when I hover button1, show panel2(div) when I hover button2. But the problem now is that the panel won't align top with the button. I've tried "Vertical-Align, Align-items", still couldn't figure out how to do it, please help! [image]

[image]

But it always display like this:[image]

Here is my code
HTML:

```
<div class="Nav">
  <span id='Span_Nav'>
    <button class="Btn_Nav" id="Btn_Nav_Equipment" >
      <div class="Panel_Nav" id='Panel_Equipment'></div>
        <span>
          <label class="Lb_Nav">Equipment</label>
        </span>
    </button>
    <button class="Btn_Nav" id="Btn_Nav_Report">
      <div class="Panel_Nav" id='Panel_Report' ></div>
        <span>
           <label class="Lb_Nav">Report</label>
        </span>
    </button>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Btn_Nav{
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  height: 6vh;
}
.Btn_Nav > span{
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;
}
.Btn_Nav > span > label.Lb_Nav{
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
}
#Span_Nav{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top:10vh;
}
button > div.Panel_Nav {
  margin-top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition: linear .3s;
  vertical-align: top;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 500%;
  height: 6vh;
  background: #0f5787;
  border: 2px solid;
  outline: none;
}
button:hover > div.Panel_Nav {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/boda4mj2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your answer here https://jsfiddle.net/g3yL9cro/1/

```
.Btn_Nav{
    position: relative;
}

button:hover > div.Panel_Nav {
    top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: Based on OP's fiddle

```
.Btn_Nav > span{
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: none;
}
.Btn_Nav > span > label.Lb_Nav{
    background: transparent;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: inline-block;
}
#Span_Nav{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    top:10px;
}
button > div.Panel_Nav {
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition: linear .3s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 500%;
    height: 20px;
    background: #0f5787;
    outline: none;
}
button:hover > div.Panel_Nav {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Update 1: 
CSS code

```
body {
    padding: 5px;
  background: blue;
}

.Btn_Nav{
  width: 10%;
  background: #eee;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.Btn_Nav > span > label.Lb_Nav{
  color: #333;
  background: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}
#Span_Nav{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
button > div.Panel_Nav {
  margin-top: -2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition: linear .3s;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 12%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 18px;
  background: #0f5787;
}
button:hover > div.Panel_Nav {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Adding a top value fixes the issue.

```
button:hover > div.Panel_Nav {
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, because all of the panel will locate beside button1.

Comment: You could use tables to create such views. Much easier in my opinion.

Comment: You have given viewport height to height instead of pixels so based on the pages height the divs size is changing.

Comment: How is it gonna work using tables? I'm a beginner. :P

Comment: If the above code works can you mark it as accepted.
Well if you are a beginner html tables with this functionality will be challenging. You can read about and see for yourself if it works: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp. Basically, you need to put the buttons in one column td and the div which shows on hover in the adjacent column td and target the next td on hover. Use `vertical-align: top` to align the elements.